# How to compare list against column of dataframe, and remove elements from list if elements match between dataframe column and list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, pandas, list-comparison

I have a df that looks like this:

```
number
1
2
3
4
```

A list that looks like this:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

How do I compare the list and the column in dataframe, while removing the elements in the list that match in the dataframe?

New list would be:

```
lst = [5]
```

To add the column in the datafrrame has many numbers that repeat so only need to remove the number once if it is in both list and column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`numpy.setdiff1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html) or substract `set`s:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4],columns=['number']) 
print (df)

lst = [1,2,3,4,5]

L = np.setdiff1d(lst, df['number'])
print (L)
[5]
```

Or:

```
L = list(set(lst) - set(df['number']))
print (L)
[5]
```